# Laravel Elixir - run version task from extension

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I'd like to make an extension for Laravel Elixir.
In my own extension I need to run an existent Elixir `version()` task.
How can I do this?

A bit of my code:

```
// File: elixir-extensions.js

var gulp   = require('gulp');
var Elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

var Task = Elixir.Task;

Elixir.extend('recursive', function(dir) {

    new Task('recursive', function(dir) {
        // Generate files list for versioning...
        var files = []; 

        // ...

        // Here I need to run Laravel Elixir version(files) with my files list

    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try this example: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#writing-elixir-extensions ? Here *say* task is called from extension.

Comment: Yes I've tried the example. But I need to run an existent Laravel Elixir task version() with my generated files list.